# another way to connect with WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

A few days ago, I started to work with **WSO2 Identity Server** in my project as an *authorization server* in my architecture, I found that it can be interfaced with an external data source like LDAP, then I can use the enterprise LDAP instead re-create all users and roles in WSO2 IS.
My question is about authentication on WSO2 IS, when the user authenticates on WSO2 IS and approves access normally this is done by HTTPS protocol. 
I don't know if it's possible to use another authentication protocol like Kerberos or Radius to connect to WSO2 IS?

Answer (score 0):

by default the WSO2 IS on the frontend supports OAuth 2.0, SAML 2.0, OpenID and WS-Trust STS protocol. They are indeed all based on the HTTPS. Next to that you may use Kerberos KDC.

For Kerberos configuration you may check this article. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/07/kerberos-authentication-using-wso2-products/

g.

Comment: Can you please give an answer to this question on :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306243/wso2-is-login-with-radius-kerberos ?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2IS has the kerberos support [1]. But it doesn't support RADIUS yet.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Kerberos+Security

Comment: We implemented RADIUS support by custom Authenticator implementation with TinyRadius library