# WSO2 IS login with Radius / Kerberos

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication, kerberos, kerberos-delegation, wso2-identity-server

The picture bellow shows the architecture that I need to deploy, and it explains my problem.

I already designed a sub system that contains a set of applications (web services, web applications) deployed in apache tomcat. To provide the SSO functionality to my sub-system I used the WSO2 Identity Server with SAML2.0 to authenticate users and get access to all sub-system applications.

This sub system is destined to be integrated into enterprises environment and work together with enterprise components. Now I need that enterprise users get access to my applications (of sub-system) there is two cases:

1. Connect WSO2 Identity Server to the enterprise LDAP, the WSO2 IS
   authenticate users by requesting the enterprise LDAP. **This is not
   recommended**.
2. Make WSO2 IS to work with the enterprise authentication server
   (Kerberos, Radius, CAS, etc.), the WSO2 :**Brokred Authentication**.

[image]

**How to authenticate automatically to wso2 IS with a Kerberos. ticket obtained from kerberos authentication (or Radius) ?**

Answer (score 1):

In fact - Kerberos is directly supported by WSO2 IS (http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/07/kerberos-authentication-using-wso2-products/ or search the web)

We achieved the RADIUS support by implementing custom Authenticator interface ( search the web for it, there are many examples, it helps if you understand OSGi architecture) and TinyRadius library (http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/)

Have fun

G.